# Eigenfunctions of 1D gaussian kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

Heads up Im a physicist!

I want to know *explicitly* the eigenfunctions of the 1D gaussian kernel
$$
K(x,y) = e^{-(x-y)^2/\sigma^2}
$$
when it is integrated, that is
$$
(Kf)(n,x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x-y)^2/\sigma^2}f(n,y)dy = \lambda(n) f(n,x),
$$
where $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ and $n$ is a possibly continuous label of the $n$th eigenfunction and eigenvalue. I’m open

What is the explicit form of $f$ and $\lambda$? I have been reading that they are related to harmonic functions in a hypersphere (?) but I didn’t understand it.

---

Perhaps relevant links

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152694/gaussian-kernel-eigenfunctions

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/236979/about-eigen-functions-of-the-gaussian-kernel

Comment: Why do you expect there even is an explicit form for this $[0,1]$ case?

Comment: @Ian I dont know. I would be happy if someone answered my question with any other limits $[a,b]$. Potentially $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Comment: In the case $(-\infty,\infty)$ there is an interpretation in terms of a random walk with centered normally distributed increments, which might be well enough studied to have a closed form expression. I doubt it though. Maybe give the citation that you mentioned about harmonic functions?

Comment: @Ian I added the links in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the Fourier transform of both sides of
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x-y)^2/\sigma^2}f(y)\,dy = \lambda f(x), \tag{1}
$$
we obtain
$$
\sqrt{\pi}\sigma e^{-\frac{1}{4}\sigma^2k^2}F(k)=\lambda F(k)
\implies \left[\sqrt{\pi}\sigma e^{-\frac{1}{4}\sigma^2k^2}
-\lambda\right]F(k)=0, \tag{2}
$$
where $F(k)$ is the Fourier transform of $f(x)$. The general solution to Eq. $(2)$ is
$$
F(k)=c_1\delta(k-k_{\lambda})+c_2\delta(k+k_{\lambda}), \tag{3}
$$
where $c_1,c_2$ are arbitrary constants and $\pm k_{\lambda}$ are the real roots of the equation
$$
\sqrt{\pi}\sigma e^{-\frac{1}{4}\sigma^2k^2}=\lambda. \tag{4}
$$
The spectrum is continuous, but bounded: Eq. $(4)$ has real roots iff $0<\lambda\leq\sqrt{\pi}\sigma$.

Taking the inverse Fourier transform of $F(k)$, we conclude that the eigenfunctions of $K$ associated with the eigenvalue $\lambda$ are arbitrary linear combinations of $e^{ik_{\lambda}x}$ and $e^{-ik_{\lambda}x}$, or, in terms of real functions, of $\cos(k_{\lambda}x)$ and $\sin(k_{\lambda}x)$. Alternatively, we may say that $f_k(x)=a\cos(kx)+b\sin(kx)$ is an eigenfunction of $K$ associated with  the eigenvalue $\lambda(k)=\sqrt{\pi}\sigma e^{-\frac{1}{4}\sigma^2k^2}$ $(0\leq k<\infty)$.

Comment: Great answer! Could you elaborate a bit on how you got the general solution to (2)? Naively, equation (2) suggests that either $F(k)=0$, the trivial solution, or $\sqrt{\pi} e^{-\sigma^2k^2/4}=\lambda$ with arbitrary $F(k)$.

Comment: Let's fix the value of $\lambda$. Eq. $(2)$ has the form $\phi(\lambda,k)F(k)=0$, where $\phi(\lambda,k):=\sqrt{\pi}\sigma e^{-\frac{1}{4}\sigma^2k^2}-\lambda$. As you noted, if $\phi(\lambda,k)\neq 0$, then $F(k)=0$. If, on the other hand, $k=k_{\lambda}$ is a zero of $\phi(\lambda,k)$, then $F(k_{\lambda})$ --- not $F(k)$ for arbitrary $k$ --- can be nonzero. However, in order to have a nontrivial inverse Fourier transform, $F$ cannot be simply the function $F(k)=0$ if $k\neq k_{\lambda}$, $F(k)=C$ if $k=k_{\lambda}$ --- it must be a Dirac delta with support in $\{k_{\lambda}\}$.